# Spark Streaming DF Parallel Processing

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I'm facing issue in  parallel processing of records in Spark Streaming Data Frame.
Flow is as :
Kafka Topic--> Spark Streaming (Data Frame)--->Implement BusinessRule-->Send result to Kafka topic.
Current code is processing  the data in Sequence, Spark Streaming(DataFrame) job is running fine
but it is time consuming(due to sequence processing of each records  in foreach()).
Per min Kafka is producing 300 messages and Spark is taking 30 min to process it. Business rule is not complicated.

**Problem:**

I'm trying to call Parallel function on top of Foreach() but once I call it, Spark is  processing same record multiple times.
I would appreciate your help if you could help to achieve parallelism at this point.

**Environment Details:**

1)Data Format :Json

2)Data Details

customer,deptid,grade,details

Cust1,22,C1,maf

Cust2,23,C2,painting

Cust3,24,C3,transport

Cust4,22,C4,general

3)Spark Version: 2.4.0 on CDH 6.3

4)Scala: 2.11.11

5)Straming : Spark Streaming DataFreame

6)Partition : 3

7)Broker :3

**Here is code snippet.**

```
val df = spark.readStream.format("kafka").option("kafka.bootstrap.servers",get_details("kafka_bootstrap_server")).option("subscribe",get_details("topic_ora")).option("startingOffsets", get_details("startingOffsets")).load()

val input_data = stream_action_function_data.select($"customer",$"deptid",$"grade",$"details")

val check_User=input_data.writeStream.foreachBatch ((batchDF: DataFrame, batchId: Long) => {
batchDF.persist()

val funcn = batchDF.collect.par.foreach( col =>  {  
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
import spark.implicits._  
val data=col
println(data)
val descri= data.getString(4)

import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{StructType, StructField, StringType,TimestampType,IntegerType};
println("Description  "+ descri)  

val sc=spark.sparkContext

val rdd = sc.parallelize(Seq(data))

val schema = StructType(Array(StructField("customer", StringType, true),StructField("deptid", StringType, true),StructField("grade", StringType, true),StructField("details", StringType, true)

val df_record=spark.createDataFrame(rdd, schema) 

if ( df_record.getString(4)== "general")
{ 
Send KafkaTopicA()//Send Schema contents to Kafka Topic A in json format                                }  
else 
{ 
Send KafkaTopicB()//Send Schema contents to Kafka Topic B in json format    
}               
})

batchDF.unpersist() 

}).option("checkpointLocation",s"$functions_checkpointLocation").outputMode("append").start()*
```

**Input Data:**

Cust4,22,C4,general

Cust1,22,C1,maf

Cust2,23,C2,painting

Cust3,24,C3,transport

**Expected output:**

Topic A:

Cust4,22,C4,general

Topic B:

Cust1,22,C1,maf

Cust2,23,C2,painting

Cust3,24,C3,transport

**Actual output:**

Topic A:

Cust4,22,C4,general

Cust4,22,C4,general

Cust4,22,C4,general

Topic B:

Cust1,22,C1,maf

Cust2,23,C2,painting

Cust3,24,C3,transport

Cust1,22,C1,maf

Cust2,23,C2,painting

Cust3,24,C3,transport

Thanks!!

Comment: Is the .par required?

Comment: Your business rules only consist in depending of the first field sending to a different topic?

Comment: Q:Is the .par required? – thebluephantom 9 hrs go 
A#: yes. As of now Spark Streaming is processing data in Sequence, I want to process in Parallel. 
Batch has number of records. So lets say in micro batch, there are 200 records. If we use Foreach without .parr, then it will be processing in sequence.
To achieve better performance and parallelism, .parr  invokes two different thread.
Please let me know know if there is other option to achieve parallism.

Comment: Q: Your business rules only consist in depending of the first field sending to a different topic? –
A#: Yes, Based on Conditional, messages will be sent to two different topic. 
to simplify, lets say all even number goes to KafkaTopic A and All Odd number goes to Kafka Topic B.

Answer (score 0):

Please try implementing the business logic under `foreachPartitions()` in order to achieve distribution of data across executors, eventually facilitating the parallelism. `collect()` operation on the other hand, executes at driver level, and thus does not play any role in achieving parallelism.

Comment: Thanks Mohit. We tried foreachPartiton but still same performance. 
Foreach.parr is causing duplication. I noticed that with in forach() we have heavy business logic that takes 5-6 seconds and once it is completed, we are commititing Kafka offset. Now it is possible that batch is inside the foreach and multiple executor consume same records , run business logic for 5-6 seconds and then commit. Can it be root cause? Plz suggest solution.

Comment: There are multiple aspects to it, which could be discussed. What is the size of data being streamed through for any given batch per say, and what is the spark configuration you are providing against it. Additionally, the topic you are trying to consume from, comprise of how many partitions, and the final output provides with you same number of part files as well?